# codeigniter mysql left join include select

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to convert the left join include select to codeigniter sql method? Thanks. I just want to know.

```
SELECT c1.c1_id, c1.c1_name, c2.c2_id, c2.c2_name, c2.c2_type, c2.c2_status, f.f_id, f.f_name, f2.f2_id, f2.f2_name FROM category2 c2 
LEFT JOIN category1 c1 ON c1.c1_id = c2.c1_id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT c2_id, f_id, f_name FROM file ORDER BY f_id DESC
) f ON f.c2_id = c2.c2_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT c2_id, f2_id, f2_name FROM file2 ORDER BY f2_id DESC
) f2 ON f2.c2_id = c2.c2_id
WHERE c2.c2_status = 1
GROUP BY c2.c2_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sub query way of codeigniter to do this for this purpose you will have to hack codeigniter. like this
Go to system/database/DB_active_rec.php Remove public or protected keyword from these functions

```
public function _compile_select($select_override = FALSE)
public function _reset_select()
```

Now subquery writing in available And now here is your query with active record

```
$select =   array('DISTINCT c2_id','f_id','f_name');
$this->db->select($select);
$this->db->from('file');
$this->db->order_by('f_id','DESC');
$subQuery1 = $this->db->_compile_select();

unset($select);

$this->db->_reset_select();

$select =   array('DISTINCT c2_id','f_id','f2_name');
$this->db->select($select);
$this->db->from('file2');
$this->db->order_by('f2_id','DESC');
$subQuery2 = $this->db->_compile_select();

unset($select); 

$this->db->_reset_select();

// And now your main query

$select =   array(
                  'c1.c1_id',
                  'c1.c1_name',
                  'c2.c2_id',
                  'c2.c2_name',
                  'c2.c2_type',
                  'c2.c2_status',
                  'f.f_id',
                  'f.f_name',
                  'f2.f2_id',
                  'f2.f2_name'
            );

$this->db->select($select);
$this->db->from('category2 c2');
$this->db->join("($subQuery1)",'f.c2_id = c2.c2_id','left');
$this->db->join("($subQuery2)",'f2.c2_id = c2.c2_id','left');
$this->db->where('c2.c2_status',1);
$this->db->group_by('c2.c2_id');
$main_query = $this->db->get();
```

And the thing is done. Cheers!!!
Note : While using sub queries you must use

```
$this->db->from('myTable')
```

instead of

```
$this->db->get('myTable')
```

which runs the query.

Now, you can check query that has been built as

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query='SELECT c1.c1_id, c1.c1_name, c2.c2_id, c2.c2_name, c2.c2_type, c2.c2_status, f.f_id, f.f_name, f2.f2_id, f2.f2_name FROM category2 c2 
LEFT JOIN category1 c1 ON c1.c1_id = c2.c1_id 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT c2_id, f_id, f_name FROM file ORDER BY f_id DESC
) f ON f.c2_id = c2.c2_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT c2_id, f2_id, f2_name FROM file2 ORDER BY f2_id DESC
) f2 ON f2.c2_id = c2.c2_id
WHERE c2.c2_status = ?
GROUP BY c2.c2_id';
$params=array();
$params[]=1;
$result=$this->db->query($query,$params);
$result=$result->result_array();
print_r($result);
```

I would avoid using Codeigniter's Active Record class unless your goal is to obfuscate your code.

"Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live."