# Codeigniter Active Record Select statement with not so normal statements

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Yea, Ill admit the subject to this post is not perfect. However I have no idea how to word it currently.

What I am trying to do is avoid the `$this->db->query($sql);` type of statement. I would prefer to use this in an active record method, but I am unsure how to do that at the moment.

my Query is set to look something to the concept of

```
select loc.distance,
loc.user,
loc.lat,
loc.lon,
baseinfo.firstname,
baseinfo.lastname,
(((acos(sin((".$this->db->escape($lat)."*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((".$this->db->escape($lat)."*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$this->db->escape($lon)." - `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS `distance`
FROM memb_geo_locations loc
```

Then it gets a little more extensive as I build out the rest with potential `LEFT JOINS`, `JOINS`, etc..

But this guy..

```
(((acos(sin((".$this->db->escape($lat)."*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((".$this->db->escape($lat)."*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$this->db->escape($lon)." - `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS `distance`
```

I am not sure how to tie that into the active record method, and I am seeking some help. Any ideas?

Comment: I have recently given an answer about that you can check.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400938/codeigniter-mysql-left-join-include-select/15402766#15402766

Comment: I'm kinda understanding that, notion, but at the same time not so much, as its a bit different than what I think I am looking for overall. That and if I can (and I have to this date), stay out of the system folder and editing any files within, as I don't want to cause potential conflict down the road when it comes time to upgrade CI (if they ever push a notable release worthy of upgrading)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $this->db->select('loc.distance,
        loc.user,
        loc.lat,
        loc.lon,
        baseinfo.firstname,
        baseinfo.lastname,
        (((acos(sin(('.$this->db->escape($lat).'*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos(('.$this->db->escape($lat).'*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos((('.$this->db->escape($lon).' - `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS `distance`
        ');
        $this->db->from('loc');
       //then all stuffs you need more... like
       $this->db->join();
       //etc..
      $query = $this->db->get('memb_geo_locations');
      return $query->result();
```